# Selenium FirefoxProfile does not add the Shoppingbuddy extension

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am testing browsers with the shoppingbuddy extension, and I cannot get the Firefox extension working.
I see a whitespace in the addon bar, so I assume it does load the extension, but does not initialize it.
Shoppingbuddy is supposed to show a welcome page, but I do not get one.
Other extensions work perfectly fine.

The code I use:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension('./shoppingbuddy-5.3.2-fx.xpi')
profile.add_extension('./i_dont_care_about_cookies-2.5.6-an+fx.xpi')

driver = RemoteWebDriver(command_executor=browserstack_url, desired_capabilities=pref_cap, browser_profile=profile)
```

If you wish to try it out yourself, [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/532046/addon-532046-latest.xpi?src=dp-btn-primary) is the link for a direct download of the Shoppingbuddy extension

I have it working on Chrome with the following code:

```
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_extension(extension_path)
chrome_options.add_extension(extension_path2)
pref_cap.update(chrome_options.to_capabilities())

driver = RemoteWebDriver(command_executor=browserstack_url, desired_capabilities=pref_cap)
```